# jnlp log4j ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, log4j, java-web-start, classnotfoundexception, jnlp

I was trying to deploy a Java application with Java Web Start, but keep getting errors. The application works fine when I run it from Eclipse or command line. My app uses some third party libraries that I defined in a separate jnlp file. If you have any ideas or suggestions, please share.
I am using Tomcat 7.0, copied jnlp files in ROOT folder and all the libs are in a separate lib folder also in the ROOT.

Here's my main jnlp file - main.jnlp:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.7+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/" href="main.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Sample</title>
        <vendor>None</vendor>
    </information>

    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>

    <resources>
        <extension name="other-libs" href="other-libs.jnlp"/>
        <extension name="log4j" href="log4j.jnlp"/>
        <jar href="lib/sample.jar" main="true"/>
        <j2se version="1.7+" java-vm-args="-ea" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    </resources>

    <application-desc main-class="org.slt.sample.SampleFile">
        <argument>C:/sample.pdf</argument>
        <argument>sample.pdf</argument>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Here's other-libs.jnlp:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.7+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/" href="other-libs.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Others</title>
        <vendor>None</vendor>
    </information>

    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>

    <resources>
        <jar href="lib/tflander-pdfbox-2.0.2.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar" download="eager"/>
        <jar href="lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar" download="eager"/>
        <jar href="lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar" download="eager"/>
    </resources>
    <component-desc/>
</jnlp>
```

Here's log4j.jnlp:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.7+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/" href="log4j.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Log</title>
        <vendor>None</vendor>
    </information>

    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>

    <resources>
        <property name="log4j.configuration" value="log4j.xml"/>
    </resources>
    <component-desc/>
</jnlp>
```

Here's the error that I get when launching main.jnlp:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
at org.tflander.org.apache.commons.logging.Log.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at org.tflander.org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(Unknown Source)
at org.tflander.org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at org.tflander.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:70)
at org.slt.sample.SampleFile.main(SampleFile.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
org.tflander.pdf.PdfException: Reason 11: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at org.tflander.pdf.PdfException.A(PdfException.java:60)
    at org.tflander.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:90)
    at org.slt.sample.SampleFile.main(SampleFile.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at org.tflander.org.apache.commons.logging.Log.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.tflander.org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(Unknown Source)
    at org.tflander.org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.tflander.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:70)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
Finished
```

Comment: I assume you checked, that lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar does exist? With the right numbers and case sensitief?

Comment: @Steffen Nieuwenhoven Yes, I have checked that, everything is fine. I actually copied the log4j jar's name into the jnlp, so the file name matches. I have also checked that log4j-1.2.17.jar has the missing Logger class, and it's there.

Comment: I suggest you open `Java Control Panel`, check all *Debugging* option in *Advanced* tab. Starting your application and verify which resouce is loaded in *Java console*.